# rails | how to make form send the dynamic id of the button clicked as a value in params and not as a key in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running rails 5.1.6

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to iterate through the @categories and foreach one:

- create a button with value => category.name 
  and id => category.id ?
  and be able to receive this id of the button pressed in the controller?

**Long version**

I have a form which displays some textfields to fill in.

Then I have @categories array.
I create one button for each category I have. If the user presses any of the category buttons, we go to the controller to update a database record and set a column value to the category the user selected.

I want the display name of the buttons to be category.category_name. 
Also I want to send to the controller the category.id when the user clicks a button.

I have this in my view

```
<%= form_with scope: :transactions, url: transactions_path, local: true do |form| %>
<p>
    <%= form.label @transaction[:title] %>
    <%= form.text_field :new_title %>
</p>
<p>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <%= form.fields_for category, index: category.id do |category_form| %>
            <%= submit_tag category.category_name, name: category.id %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

What I get in the controller as params is

```
Parameters: { "20"=>"Food"}
```

This means that in the controller the only way to get the category id is to search in the keys for an integer. This is not good code.

if I remove the `name:` attribute in the `submit_tag` I get `params[:commit]=> "Food"`
so I get the category_name and not the id.

If I use hidden fields, I get all the category ids and names in the params hash, with no idea in the controller which category the user clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your categories should actually be radio buttons instead of being submit buttons themselves. Because you can only choose one category.
So instead of generating so many submit buttons, create radio buttons (which you can style the same way as the submit button).

Then in order to retrieve the same behaviour, as before, you should hide the submit button and with javascript add an event listener which submits the form as soon as one of the radio buttons is clicked.
Something along these lines.

```
<%= form_with scope: :transactions, url: transactions_path, local: true do |form| %>
<p>
    <%= form.label @transaction[:title] %>
    <%= form.text_field :new_title %>
</p>
<p>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <%= form.fields_for category, index: category.id do |category_form| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:age, category.id) %>
            <%= label_tag(:age_child, category.category_name, class: "category-button") %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= submit_tag category.category_name, name: category.id, class: "hidden" %>
</p>

<% end %>

<script>
let form = document.getElementById('put-form-if-here')
let categoryButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.category-button')

Array.from(categoryButtons).forEach((button) => {
  button.addEvenListener('click', () => {
    form.submit()
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: This worked thank you. I just added the `class: "category-button"` to the `radio_button_tag` and not the `label_tag`. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

So, yes you can.  Just a feature of raw HTML (not of Rails), the `name` and `value` attributes of the submit button that's used to submit a form are sent as params.  Unfortunately, the `value` is also used for the button label, so it has always been awkward to use these values as data.

The options generally used are either:

1. What you're doing, ie. using the `name` as the actual value, and then searching for it through the params.  As you say, not a nice solution.
2. Using multiple forms, one for each submit button.
3. Use Javascript to add the data you want as a hidden field to the form just as it's being submitted by hooking into the onsubmit event of the form, and using data attributes in your submit tag.

The latter is, IMHO, the only nice solution.